# A special case of accessing parameters from servlet where they are encrypted and contain &,= value

Tags: java, servlets, request, httprequest

I need to implement a URL which looks something like below one. The Notable thing is that its only one parameter i need to access and the value that's supposed to be held by the parameter is encrypted which may contains characters like & and =.

Example 1.

www.abc.com/disp?v=qww78agd=

The parameter v in above url contains value qww78agd=.

Supposing the encryption turns out the following way.

Example 2.

www.abc.com/disp?v=qww7&f=iuy68=

www.abc.com/disp?v=qww7&f==iuy68=

Then servlet will take v and f as two separate parameters, whereas i want to obatain qww7&f==iuy68= from parameter.

I thought of taking up all key value pairs from request HashMap and concatenating the joints via & and =. But the problem is that two consecutive = signs as in second case of example 2, its treated as only one equal to in request key,value map. Hence, my other = sign(s) are lost.

Is there any way such that i can get query string part as it is on my servlet and parse it using string processing on my own? 
or any other approach?

Comment: You're supposed to URL-encode `&`.

Comment: Those are not valid parameters. Special characters like `=` or `&` are encoded by the browser, and automatically decoded by the server. You don't need to do anything special, except encoding the parameter values if you're generating URLs yourself: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: Chris :The servlet is a widget implemention where in iframe url of such kind is provided. There is no opportunity to embed any kind of js due to security concerns.

Comment: @JB Nizet : How do i get the entire query string chunk. In order to use that encoder tool i must be able to obtain that exact thing from query string portion. How do i get that?

Comment: An encoder is used to **generate** a URL. To get the parameters from a request, you use `request.getParameter()`. The query string should never contain `&` and `=` characters in parameter values in the first place, because that makes the query string invalid. Fix the part of the code which generated these buggy query strings.

Comment: its encryption of a string according to some cryptographic algorithm(doesnt need any fix), that the algorithm is returning. My goal is to obtain the only the Query String portion of url.

Comment: If it's supposed to generate a valid query string, and it generates an invalid one, it definitely needs to be fixed. If it isn't supposed to generate a query string, then don't use the output as a query string. Encode the output, and generate a query string like `encrypted=the-url-encoded-encryption-output`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easy.

Using the request.getQueryString() method the query string portion is fetched as it is as string on the servlet which I processed using my own logic of string processing.